# read the first line in a file, given the file path in BASH

Tags: bash, files

I have a file stored in a location `/x/y/z/file.txt`. There is only an unsigned integer stored in this file.

How would I read it and store it into a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

> var=$(cat /x/y/z/file.txt)

The above command will print the file and assign the output to the var variable.

Another thing you can do, if you want to explicitly grab only the first line:

> var=$(head -1 /x/y/z/file.txt)

Comment: The second method looks better for me. But is it $var or only var?

Comment: It’s only “var” when populating the variable and then when you want to access the variable’s content, then you use “$var” or even better “${var}” - if the first line contains a string with spaces then writing it like so will make sure that spaces are also included as part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `read` builtin command:

```
IFS= read -r var </x/y/z/file.txt
```

The `IFS=` and `-r` bits are there to disable some "helpful" things `read` does by default -- removing whitespace at the beginning and end of the line (the `IFS=` prefix disables this), and processing backslashes as escape/continuation markers (the `-r` option disables this).